# Jenkins - Add a dynamic label to a build

Tags: jenkins, build, label

I am trying to achieve the following task in Jenkins:
1) Build a maven project
2) When running the test cases I print certain messages to the console output
3) Parse the console output of the build and determine if certain patterns exist in the output
4) If the pattern exists I want to label the build with a specific string

I have achieved steps 1-3. I am not able to create a dynamic label and tie it to a build. I have a Groovy script that parses the console output and determines if the pattern exists in the build's output.

Bamboo provides this feature to label a build based on regular expressions present in the build's console output.
Link - https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo0606/using-bamboo/jobs-and-tasks/configuring-jobs/configuring-miscellaneous-settings-for-a-job/configuring-automatic-labeling-of-job-build-results

I have gone through various existing Jenkins plugins but have not been successful in achieving this functionality. Is there a plugin to achieve this functionality or can I add additional lines in the Groovy script to create a dynamic build label.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `if` to set agent:

```
def AGENT_LABEL = null

node('master') {
  stage('Checkout and set agent'){
     checkout scm
     ### Or just use any other approach to figure out agent label: read file, etc
     if (env.BRANCH_NAME == 'master') {
        AGENT_LABEL = "prod"
     } else {
        AGENT_LABEL = "dev"
     }
   }
}

pipeline {
    agent {
       label "${AGENT_LABEL}"
    }
```